# Unable to import snap.svg to ionic2 project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, snap.svg

I followed [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/third-party-libs/) but I am not able to get *snap.svg* working in my *Ionic2* project.

Install:

```
npm install snapsvg --save
npm install @types/snapsvg --save
```

Use:

```
import * as snapsvg from 'snapsvg';
var s = snapsvg.Snap(800,600);
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Install imports-loader and snap:

```
npm i imports-loader
npm i snapsvg
npm i @types/snapsvg
```

2) Create element in html template:

```
<svg width="200" height="200" id="svg"></svg>
```

3) Import it in your component:

```
import Snap from 'imports-loader?this=>window,fix=>module.exports=0!snapsvg/dist/snap.svg.js';
```

4) Use it in your component:

```
 ionViewDidEnter() {
    let s = Snap("#svg");
    let circle = s.circle(50, 50, 100);
    ...
  }
```